# Adding Elements in a Array

Tags: ruby, arrays, algorithm

I have the following problem:

1. There is an array that consists of 6 numbers, each two digits at maximum.
2. *Y* is an array whose *i* th element is the sum of the first *i* +1 elements of the first array.
3. Accept a numerical input via keyboard. If it matches one of the numbers in *Y* display a message; If not, restart the program.

[image: Diagram]

This is the algorithm that I am thinking:

- Initialize empty array [x] & [y]
- 6.times.map{ Random.rand(1..99) }
- Add numbers using each do?
- Store in array [y ]
- Compare input to == array [y]
- If any instance matches display msg else restart

I would be really grateful for any guidance or help with this problem.

Comment: Excuse me, but what is the question of your question? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
loop do
  x = Array.new(6){rand(99)}
  y = []
  x.each{|k| y.push(k + y.last.to_i)}
  y.shift
  break if y.include?(gets.to_i)
end
puts 'message'
```

Comment: If you like, you can compute y like this: `y = x.size.times.map { |i| a[0..i].inject(&:+) }`

Comment: @Wayne That is another solution that works.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a quick stab at your problem.

```
def check_number_in_array
  x = Array.new(6)
  y = []
  begin
    x.collect! { rand(99) }
    y.clear
    sum = 0
    x.each do |i|
      sum = sum+i
      y << sum
    end
    gets
    # The following lines are just for "debugging"
    print "x = [ "
    x.each {|i| print i, " "}
    print "]\ny = [ "
    y.each {|i| print i, " "}
    print "]\n"
  end while !y.include?($_.to_i)
  puts "Good guess!"
end
```